# Capitalize various letters in a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am working on an interview question:

> Capitalize 2nd, 4th, 8th, 16th letters in a string
>
> input - "letters in a string"
>
> output - "lEtTers in a stRing"

Here is my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "letters in a string";

    String output = input.substring(0, 1) + input.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase() + input.substring(2, 3)
            + input.substring(3, 4).toUpperCase() + input.substring(4, 7) + input.substring(7, 8).toUpperCase()
            + input.substring(8, 15) + input.substring(15, 16).toUpperCase() + input.substring(15);
    System.out.println(output);

}
```

Is there any way we can generalize this without hard coding the offset numbers here? In general, what I am looking for is - given the letter number which we want to capitalize, our program should work on that without changing the core logic and should be efficient as well in terms of complexity?

Comment: make use of method/funcitons

Comment: If I may, what job are you interviewing for that does not suppose you know how to write methods?

Comment: @JunedAhsan and yet nobody here has a generalized `Capitalize(String s, int index)` which another method `Capitalize(String s, int[] indices)` could make use of in a loop. Very simple solution to implement, very reusable, very concise, etc.

Comment: @BenKnoble And method names should start with a lowercase.

Comment: Good point. I occasionally slip (as do most)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to set the character at an ever increasing range of power by 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...), you could simply use a loop.

The problem is, `String` isn't mutable (it can't be changed) and you should avoid `String` concatenation within loops where possible (okay, in your case, it's probably not a big deal, but it's still good practice).

To that end, you could either convert the `String` to a `char` array (`String#toCharArray()`) or use a `StringBuilder`, for example...

```
String text = "letters in a string";
int index = 2;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
while (index < sb.length()) {
    sb.setCharAt(index - 1, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(index - 1)));
    index *= 2;
    System.out.println(index);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Which outputs `lEtTers in a stRing`

Comment: beat me to it; I didnt think about jumping to the next index like that though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this without hard coding the offset.  Here is an example:

```
int[] toCaps = new int[]{2, 4, 8, 16};
String input = "letters in a string";
String newString = "";
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
    boolean b = false;
    for(int j : toCaps){
        if(i == (j-1)){//Subtract 1 since the indexing starts at 0.
            b = true;
        }
    }
    if(b){
        newString += Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i));
    }else{
        newString += input.charAt(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(newString);
```

Now what ever numbers are in the toCaps array will be the location of the string which is converted to uppercase.

Comment: concatenation in loops? `StringBuilder` would be better (although it is perhaps not an issue here)

Comment: @BenKnoble I don't know much about StringBuilders, so im assuming you are right.  I was just trying to avoid imports mostly.

Comment: fair enough. Like I said, in this trivial example it shouldn't matter too much. But in general, concatenating in a loop should be avoided.

Comment: @BenKnoble the loop can be avoided by creating an ArrayList and use .contains instead, but I guess it really does not matter much in this case.

Comment: Good catch. Thats why I love StackOverflow: different solutions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like

```
public static String capitalize(String s, int[] array)//array would be the indexes you want to be caps.
{
  char[] stringChars = new char[s.length];
  for(int x = 0; x < stringChars.length; x++)
  {
    stringChars[x] = s.charAt(x);
  }
  String finalString;
  boolean matches;
  for(int x = 0; x < stringChars.length; x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < array.length; y++)
    {
      if(array[y] == x)
        {
         matches = true;
         break;
        }
       if(matches == true)
         stringChars[x] = Character.toUppercase(stringChars[x]);
       finalString += stringChars[x];
    }
  }
  return finalString;
}
```

I haven't tested this code and there may be some bugs but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, the best way to do this is by writing a method which you can use more than once. Try this:

```
public static String capitalize(String string, int[] caps) {
    if (caps[caps.length - 1] > string.length()) {
        return "String not long enough.";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
    for (int i : caps) {
        sb.setCharAt(i - 1, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(i - 1)));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] caps = {2, 4, 8, 16};
    System.out.println(capitalize("letters in a string", caps));
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer well we all suggested a similar solution, one way or another.

Comment: So why repeat what has already been suggested? I can count at least 3 distinct methods. The question is, what is yours adding that the other similar answer didn't

Comment: Firstly, I suggested using a method, which he hasn't mentioned. Secondly it may be slightly 'similar' but far from being the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is I think the best way:

```
//here index is the nth letter to capitalize, i.e. 2 changes the character
//at index 1, hence the subtraction
public String capitalize(String s, int index)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb.setCharAt(index - 1, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(index - 1)));
    return (sb.toString());
}

//indices in the array should the follow the same convention as above
public String capitalize(String s, int[] indices)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
    {
        s = Capitalize(s, indices[i]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

From here calling the method on retrieved input is simple.

EDIT: After returning to look at this randomly, the creation of a StringBuilder in a loop could be costly, since it's only useful inside one method body. A better way would be to extend the pattern to pass around a StringBuilder reference to the string within the methods (in some private manner) to avoid creating a new one all the time.

Answer (score 0):

My safer implementation:

```
public static String toCapitalizedCase(String givenString) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(givenString)){
        return givenString;
    }
    String[] arr = givenString.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(arr[i].charAt(0)))
                .append(arr[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```