# capitalize special words(abbrevations) in android

Tags: android

I want to capitalize first word of abbreviations like dr. mr. etc.
search over the internet but didn't find any useful thing about it.
i tried

```
 String capitalized = WordUtils.capitalize(sb.toString(), '.', ' ');
    System.out.println(capitalized);
```

but it capitalize first word of every sentence.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to be new to programming so this almost appears to be a like a homework problem (even if it isn't). 'Search over the internet but didn't find any useful' isn't a good problem statement. And there may be no prebuilt library to do what you want. Regardless, Java Strings are just an array of characters with no understanding of a what word is. You have to define what set of words your code will act upon. So while you want 'Dr.' from 'dr.' what about 'etc' or 'e.g.'. Good luck.

Comment: how do you recognize that the first letter of the word should be capitalized? Just in words, not in Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a regex that could find title like `mr.` `dr.`, etc.. [RegEx: Match Mr. Ms. etc in a "Title" Database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217326/regex-match-mr-ms-etc-in-a-title-database-field)
2. Prepare an array with indexes that need to be capitalised.
3. Create utility method that does the conversion process. [Capitalize various letters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447469/capitalize-various-letters-in-a-string)